# Read written text from NFC with the PN532 Hat and displaying it in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nfc, pn532

I'm trying to extract a short line of text written on an NFC tag. The Waveshare examples only show the UID of the tag as far as I know, so my question is: Is it even possible to read texts/urls/etc. from nfc tags using Python, or not? If so, would anyone happen to know how to get this to work.

Comment: See https://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/get-started.html#read-and-write-tags for reading Ndef records off a tag as Ndef format is a common way to store text/urls/etc